# Error 1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type Function

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I keep getting the error "Error 1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type Function" in my Actionscript 3.0 file.

The code I have is:

```
var myBox:Object = new Object();
colourcb.addEventListener("change", myBox);

myBox.change = function(){
outline.gotoAndStop(colourcb.value);
}
```

I am trying to change the frame of a movie clip with the use of a combo box. Any help would be hugely appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have mixed AS2 and AS3 syntax. try this:

```
colourcb.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeHandler);

function changeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    outline.gotoAndStop(colourcb.value);
}
```